# Resgatar somente o corpo da resposta MultiPart

Tags: java, android, json, download

Estou tentando fazer o download de um arquivo JSON, ele me é enviado via MultiPart, eu consigo recuperar ele porém não quero salvar em um arquivo físico, então eu estou pegando o retorno e convertendo em string. Meu problema está na conversão pois ele me traz os headers do multi part assim eu não conssigo converter ele para um objeto json. Tem como eu remover esses header e ficar somente com o corpo da resposta sem a necessidade de gravar o arquivo ?

abaixo tem um exemplo da resposta em string.

> --e237ecf6-b3ab-4eb0-b94a-8077a7abb566
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name=ListaPrevias; filename=ListaPrevias
>
> [{"CodigoEmpresa":"1",.........................]

Abaixo tem a método que estou utilizando.

```
public static JSONObject downloadMultiPart(String url) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject resposta = new JSONObject();
    String respws;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        Log.i("HDEBUG","Download de JSON - URL ["+url+"]");
         
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(30000); // 30 segundos de time out
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(false);
        con.connect();
         
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
         
        while ( is.read(b) != -1)
            baos.write(b);
         
        con.disconnect();
        
        respws = new String(baos.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
        
        Multipart multi = new Multipart(respws);
        String corpo = multi.getSubType();
        
        resposta.put("ok",true);
        resposta.put("resposta", corpo.toString());
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        resposta.put("ok",false);
        resposta.put("resposta","");
    }
     
    return resposta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Galera eu refiz tudo e agora funcionou, segue abaixo o código espero que seja útil a vocês.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public static JSONObject downloadMultiPart(String url) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject resposta = new JSONObject();
    String respws;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        URL urlx = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conection = urlx.openConnection();
        conection.connect();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlx.openStream(),
                8192);

        String caminho = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OsManager.kml";

        try{
            File f = new File (caminho);
            f.delete();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("HDEBUG","Arquivo ainda não existe.");
        }

       FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(caminho);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();

        output.close();
        input.close();


        String linha = "";
        BufferedReader arquivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(caminho));
        int contador = 0;
        while(arquivo.ready()) {    
            String tmp_linha = arquivo.readLine();
            if(contador == 3)
            {
                linha = tmp_linha;
            }
            contador = contador + 1;
        }
        File filem = new File(caminho);
        filem.delete();

        resposta.put("ok", true);
        resposta.put("resposta", linha);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        resposta.put("ok",false);
        resposta.put("resposta","");
    }

    return resposta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de `getSubType()`, Use o método [`getBodyParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Multipart.html#getBodyPart(int)) para recuperar uma lista que contém realmente o corpo da mensagem. O conteúdo deve estar em um dos elementos da lista, que na verdade provavelmente tem apenas um elento.

O retorno do método será um `BodyPart`. O conteúdo poderá ser acessado pelo método [`getEntity`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.10/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/BodyPart.html#getEntity()).

Porém, às vezes, o corpo de uma mensagem *multipart* é outra mensagem *multipart*. Então pode ser que você tenha que "descer" outro nível, isto é, o objeto (entidade) retornado pelo `getEntity` pode ser outro `MultiPart`.

Se tiver dúvidas, poste uma cópia da mensagem completa para que se possa analisá-la.

Comment: no lugar de multi.getSubType(); eu usaria o multi.getBodyPart(); ?

Comment: @HiagoSouza Sim, mas a diferença é que não retornaria uma `String`.

Comment: Então mais aqui no caso só tenho o método getBodyParts

Comment: Na realidade acredito que é a maneira em que estou recebendo esse arquivo, o método que estou usando é correto para receber o multipart ?

Comment: @HiagoSouza Acabei de perceber que estamos falando de APIs diferentes. Reformulei a resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou =/

Comment: respws = new String(baos.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
         
         Multipart multi = new Multipart(respws);
         BodyPart corpo = (BodyPart) multi.getBodyParts();
         
         HttpEntity corpofinal = ((HttpResponse) corpo).getEntity();
         
         resposta.put("ok",true);
         resposta.put("resposta", corpofinal.getContent());

Comment: @HiagoSouza *"Não funcionou"* é muito vago. Eu já disse que sem ver o contéudo da mensagem não tem como ter certeza da implementação. Acabou a bateria da minha bola de cristal. Além disso, você está tentando colocar a resposta num objeto JSON, mas nem está verificando o que o `getContent` retornou. O Java não vai converter o conteúdo em Json automaticamente. Provavelmente é uma String e você vai ter que converter de String para Json.

Comment: Ok, eu quis diser que não me trouxe conteúdo algum. Da outra maneira ele traz o conteúdo porém com as informações do multipart, se eu salvar o arquivo e abrir ele novamente funciona, porém é um passo a mais e como tenho um conteúdo grande demora mais. Vou tentar novamente e retorno para você oque aconteceu.